# Parse STEP-file (with javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, peg, step

I'm trying to read the information from a STEP-file ([ISO 10303-21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303-21)) with javascript. I'm not sure how to tackle this at all.

I have found open source alternatives but in all languages but Javascript... So I'm not able to learn much from them.

Since the text is rather irregular it's really hard to just use a regular expression to extract the information.

```
ISO-10303-21;
HEADER;
FILE_DESCRIPTION(
/* description */ ('A minimal AP214 example with a single part'),
/* implementation_level */ '2;1');
FILE_NAME(
/* name */ 'demo',
/* time_stamp */ '2003-12-27T11:57:53',
/* author */ ('Lothar Klein'),
/* organization */ ('LKSoft'),
/* preprocessor_version */ ' ',
/* originating_system */ 'IDA-STEP',
/* authorization */ ' ');
FILE_SCHEMA (('AUTOMOTIVE_DESIGN { 1 0 10303 214 2 1 1}'));
ENDSEC;
DATA;
#10=ORGANIZATION('O0001','LKSoft','company');
#11=PRODUCT_DEFINITION_CONTEXT('part definition',#12,'manufacturing');
#12=APPLICATION_CONTEXT('mechanical design');
#13=APPLICATION_PROTOCOL_DEFINITION('','automotive_design',2003,#12);
#14=PRODUCT_DEFINITION('0',$,#15,#11);
#15=PRODUCT_DEFINITION_FORMATION('1',$,#16);
#16=PRODUCT('A0001','Test Part 1','',(#18));
#17=PRODUCT_RELATED_PRODUCT_CATEGORY('part',$,(#16));
#18=PRODUCT_CONTEXT('',#12,'');
#19=APPLIED_ORGANIZATION_ASSIGNMENT(#10,#20,(#16));
#20=ORGANIZATION_ROLE('id owner');
#21=IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('Visa 2D F\S\dstpunkter i 3D',$,IFCBOOLEAN(.F.),$);
ENDSEC;
END-ISO-10303-21;
```

And different export tools export with different variations:

```
#95=STYLED_ITEM('',(#94),#92);
#12 = CARTESIAN_POINT ( 'NONE',  ( 1.213, 5.617, -7.500 ) ) ;
#263 = TEST ( 'Spaces must not be ignored here' ) ;
```

[source for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246867/regex-for-instances-in-step-files)

What is the best way to read the step files? Parser generators, Regex or something else?

Answer (score 1):

First, you might want to take a look at [that conversation](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7125).

There are different grammars for STEP-file (Part 21) and different ways that might help achieve what you want to do. I haven't tested any of these methods.

- Use the [NIST ANTLR Part 21 grammar](https://sourceforge.net/p/osexpress/code/HEAD/tree/ontostep-lib/trunk/src/main/antlr3/gov/nist/msid/ontostep/instance/Part21.g) and generate the javascript out of it with [ANTLR](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md)
- Use the [BuildingSMARTLibrary](https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BuildingSMARTLibrary/tree/master/BuildingSMARTLibrary) and particularly the *nl.tue.buildingsmart.express.population*. It is a JavaCC based file-reader for STEP-files. There are ways to [convert Java parsers to Javascript with GWT](http://consoliii.blogspot.it/2014/04/creating-gwt-compatible-parser-using.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can find precisous information about the entities in the following [usage guide for PDM Schema](http://www.prostep.org/fileadmin/freie_downloads/Guidlines-UseCases/ProSTEP-iViP_Implementation-Guideline_PDM-Schema_4.3.pdf) (subset from different AP that corresponds to the Product structure). It explains the information contained in the elements and the relationship between them.

Comment: I have a good understanding of the syntax and how everything works together. This is not my problem, rather how to parse the text.